# Java - Map which prints the value as we have inserted

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there a way in java to get the values as we put the values in Map(order that we have put).

Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class to use is [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). You have a choice of insertion order and access order.

Comment: I have used LinkedHashMap but it prints the key pair from the last one but i want to print them in the order i inserted data.??

Comment: Then you should have posted the exact code that gives you trouble, with both your expected and actual output. `LinkedHashMap` (when in *insertion order* mode, the default) does iterate in the order you inserted data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, what is  insertion order mode and how to set it

Comment: Insertion order is the default, so if you haven't done anything to specifically enable acces order, that's what you have.

Comment: great marko it your input helped and resolved the issue. i have not set anything as insert order but it works as expected. :). Can we set it?

Answer (score 2):

use linkedhashmap

```
LinkedHashMap lm = new LinkedHashMap();
        lm .put("map", "LinkedHashMap");
        lm .put("1", "A");
        lm .put("2", "B");
        lm .put("3", "C");
        print(lm .keySet()); 
        print(lm .values());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) has an iterable order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). The documentation says:

```
This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked
list running   through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration
ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
(insertion-order).
```